# Vectorizing complex operations on dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to Python and using Pandas and NumPy. I have a dataframe `df` 
and I want to find values of column `OZNAKA_PARTIJE` for which the value of `KLIJENT_ID` is not unique and delete such rows.

I try to avoid loops as much as possible but the condition here seems much too complex to use the methods I know. Is there any possible way to write a vectorized version of this code, using some functions from Pandas or NumPy?

Performing this loop takes a long time and ends with a MemoryError.

```py
party_labels = df['OZNAKA_PARTIJE'].unique().tolist()

for i in party_labels:
    extracted_party_label = df.loc[df['OZNAKA_PARTIJE'] == i]

    # check if you can use the drop method below
    if (extracted_party_label[ extracted_party_label['OZNAKA_PARTIJE'] == i ].index.is_unique == False):
        print('Drop method might not work properly')

    # if there exists multiple client ids for given party label
    if (extracted_party_label['KLIJENT_ID'].is_unique == False):
        # delete rows with that party label in the original dataset
        df.drop(df[ df['OZNAKA_PARTIJE'] == i ].index , inplace=True)
```

UPDATE: answered!

Based on answer posted by @Chris I came up with this.

```py
df2 = df.copy()
gb = df2.groupby('OZNAKA_PARTIJE')['KLIJENT_ID'].nunique()
party_labels = df2['OZNAKA_PARTIJE'].unique().tolist()
mask = gb[df2['OZNAKA_PARTIJE']] == 1
df2 = df2[ mask.values ]
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a third column with any value, you can groupby the first, second, and count the third.  The count will be 1 if the first two are unique.  The count will be more if there are duplicates.  You can use this to create a boolean masks and then filter the df by that.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'a'],[1,2,'b'],[2,3,'c'],[3,4,'d'],[3,8,'e']], columns=['OZNAKA_PARTIJE', 'KLIJENT_ID', 'OTHER'])

df = df.groupby(['OZNAKA_PARTIJE','KLIJENT_ID'])['OTHER'].count() == 1
df = df.reset_index()
df[df['OTHER']==True]


OZNAKA_PARTIJE  KLIJENT_ID  OTHER
2               3           True
3               4           True
3               8           True
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to do `== True`, using `df[df['OTHER']]` is the same thing

Comment: @Chris, even though your answer isn't what I'm looking for, based on it I came up with an alternative way for grouping, but I'm still working on filtering the dataframe.